# TF Object detection API mAP calculation seemingly wrong

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I'm not sure if this is a misunderstanding on my part or a bug in the TF Object Detection (OD) API code, but I figured I'd try here first before posting to github.

Basically, I am comparing 2 models in tensorboard, red vs green. I find that red model is slightly better at overal mAP, mAP@.50IOU, & mAP@.75IOU. However, green is better at all the mAPs split by object size: mAP large, medium, and small (see image below at 67.5k steps, where blue arrow is).

Now I don't have a PhD in math, but my assumption was that if a model has higher mAP w/ small medium and large objects, it should have a higher overall mAP...

[image]

Here are the exact values: (All values obtained at 67.5k steps, without any smoothing)

```
                Red     Green
mAP             .3599   .3511
mAP@.50IOU      .5670   .5489
mAP@.75IOU      .3981   .3944
mAP (large)     .5557   .7404
mAP (medium)    .3788   .3941
mAP (small)     .1093   .1386
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a way to gain more insight is to analyze the statistics of the number of bounding box sizes (small, medium, large) in your dataset. Here is a link for [mAP calculation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/58a3de6c68639c3eac95f7c84089f320d32a85bb/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py#L171) where the TF Object Detection API describes how small boxes and medium boxes are calculated.

I can imagine that a reason this issue is happening is that you have a much higher amount of medium size bounding boxes than your large size bounding boxes. Also, I would neglect the performance of the small bounding boxes since the mAP is less than 0.01.